# Nginx - Redirecting a server_name to a different domain using location block

Tags: nginx, networking, uri, redirect, nginx-location

What I would want is for me to type in test.com/path and have it go to anothersite.com, but instead, it goes to differentsite.com. I believe I'm doing the correct formatting, but  seems to be skipping over the location block entirely.

```
server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  test.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {

        listen       443;
        listen       [::]:443;
        server_name  test.com;


        location /path {

        return 301 https://anothersite.com;
}

        return 301 https://differentsite.com;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the server block should not have a return statement. There should be two location blocks with return statements for each path

```
    server {
            listen       80;
            listen       [::]:80;
            server_name  test.com;
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }


    server {

            listen       443;
            listen       [::]:443;
            server_name  test.com;


            location / {

             return 301 https://differentsite.com;
}

            location /path {

            return 301 https://anothersite.com;
    }



    }
```